# My SKAudioNode stops when I transition to secondScene

Tags: ios, swift, transition, scene, skaudionode

I know this is meant to be fairly simple but I just can't figure it out! I have my song playing in the background in sceneOne. I then switch over to sceneTwo and the music completely stops. How can I make the background music continue? 
Below is my code.

```
//Music
Music = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "Verm - Explode.mp3")
self.addChild(Music)
```

The code above is shown in sceneOne. Please tell me how to continue it into sceneTwo. Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first scene will be released when transitioning to scene two. And your sound node is a child of the first scene, it is released as well. The right approach is not to retain the sound node across scenes, but to use `AVFoundation` framework to play background music. This is also recommended by the SpriteKit documentation. Specifically, `AVAudioPlayer` is the class you will need. It's api is fairly simple, please check its documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code it might helps you to solve your issue

```
runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1), completion: {
        self.backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(fileNamed: "main.mp3")
        self.backgroundMusic.autoplayLooped = true
        self.addChild(self.backgroundMusic)
    })
```